# Doctrine "Entity" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

In my `doctrine.php` I have the following configuration

```
<?php

// See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html

namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;

return static function (ContainerConfigurator $container) {
    $container->extension('doctrine', [
        'dbal' => [
            'url' => '%env(DATABASE_URL)%',
        ],
        'orm' => [
            'auto_generate_proxy_classes' => true,
            'auto_mapping' => true,
            'mappings' => [
                'default' => [
                    'is_bundle' => false,
                    'type' => 'annotation',
                    'dir' => '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity',
                    'prefix' => 'App\Entity',
                    'alias' => 'App'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
};
```

And my Entity class is defined as follows

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

#[Entity(repositoryClass: EntityRepository::class)]
#[Table(name: 'entity')]
class Entity

...
```

I tried accessing it like by calling `getRepository` like this

```
$entityRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(Entity::class);
```

But this fails with the `is not a valid entity or mapped super class`

P.S.

If necessary, this is my `EntityRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Entity;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class EntityRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Entity::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need Quoting Reserved Words? ie name: '`entity`'...or choose another name to test.

Comment: Oh it is different name than `entity`. I am just using that as reference. It is in fact `Country` table with `CountryRepository`. But since that was not relevant to the question I abstracted it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an issue. I am a dummy..

I had to change

```
'type' => 'annotation'
```

to

```
'type' => 'attribute'
```

Since I'm using php8 syntax. Sorry lads!